# Can not run application in Spring Boot Data Cassandra App because of syntax query error that is no viable alternative at character 'ı'

Tags: spring, cassandra, syntax-error, cql, spring-data-cassandra

I have started developing a spring boot data cassandra application. I am configuring in a SpringConfigurationClass with Cassandra. When I start the app, it throws SyntaxError and CassandraQuerySyntaxException. While starting, creating a cql for a table that is Account Entity. It has a timestamp field that is "private Date createdAt".

Normally, timestamp has a "i" character but cql has "ı" so it try to run a cql has "tımestamp".

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraQuerySyntaxException: 
 Query; CQL [CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts (created_at tımestamp, email text, id text,
 is_active boolean, passwd text, uname text, PRIMARY KEY (id));]; 
 line 1:49 no viable alternative at character 'ı'; nested exception is 
 com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.SyntaxError: 
 line 1:49 no viable alternative at character 'ı'
```

How Can I solve this problem and proceed?

My Configuration Class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories
public class CassandraConfiguration extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

@Value("${accountservice.cassandra.keyspace.name}")
private String keyspaceName;

@Value("${accountservice.cassandra.port}")
private int port;

@Value("${accountservice.cassandra.contact.point}")
private String contactPoint;

@Value("${accountservice.cassandra.uname}")
private String uname;

@Value("${accountservice.cassandra.passwd}")
private String passwd;

@Override
protected String getKeyspaceName() {
    return keyspaceName;
}

public String getPasswd() {
    return passwd;
}

public String getUname() {
    return uname;
}

@Override
protected String getContactPoints() {
    return contactPoint;
}

@Override
protected int getPort() {
    return port;
}

@Override
public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
    return new String[] {"com.trius.accountservice"};
}

@Override
public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
    return SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS;
}

@Override
public CqlSessionFactoryBean cassandraSession() {
    CqlSessionFactoryBean cqlSessionFactoryBean = super.cassandraSession();
    cqlSessionFactoryBean.setPassword(getPasswd());
    cqlSessionFactoryBean.setUsername(getUname());
    return cqlSessionFactoryBean;
}
}


My Table:
```

```
        @Data
        @Builder
        @AllArgsConstructor
        @NoArgsConstructor
        @EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
        @ToString
        @Table(value = "accounts")
        public class Account implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @Column(value="uname")
    private String username;
    @Column(value="email")
    private String email;
    @Column(value="passwd")
    private String passwd;
    @Column(value="is_active")
    private Boolean active;
    @Column(value="created_at")
    private Date createdAt;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an extended or special character has been inadvertently included in the CQL statement.

If you've copied and pasted the schema definition on a Windows machine from a file such as a Word document, make sure you clean it up first. For example, you can paste the schema into Notepad and save it as a text file then use that file as your source. Cheers!

Comment: @ErikRamirez I have a same issue. How can I fix it?

Comment: @TonyBrand you need to make sure there are no special characters included in the schema definition. Cheers!

Comment: I used "import java.time.LocalDate" instead of "import java.util.Date" and my problem is solved.